# Lawn Mower (probably) Electrical Problem

Tags: lawn-mower, engine

This is a ~2013 Troy Bilt Horse tractor.

I need some advice on how to troubleshoot my mower starting.  It cut out right when I was mowing, and had cut out intermittently for a few days before that.  It would never actually stall, just start to kind of like I had raised up the seat and grounded the dead-man switch.

Now, I have done the following:

- Checked the gas and the fuel line past the filter, and there's gas flowing.
- Verified the mower turns over, and verified 2 of the safety switches:
  1 If the brake is on, it turns over.  If the brake is off, it does not.  I take this to mean the brake safety switch is working

  2 If the PTO is dis-engaged, it turns over.  If it is engaged, it does not.  I take this to mean the PTO switch is functioning

  3 Verified that the seat switch is hooked up, and it appears to work mechanically.  I'm not sure that this is not the problem - maybe a short in the wire?

Mower turns over OK, it just won't start now.  The first maybe 5 times I tried it sounded like it was going to start then died.  Now it just turns over with no change to the noise or cadence of the motor.

What should I do to test the shorted wire?  I have removed the mower cover and can see some of the wiring harness.  I also have the spark plug and magneto accessible.

Any suggestions as to what to do?  I can't inspect the seat switch wire 100% because it goes through the body of the mower.  What's likely the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: So the starter cranks? Is the fuel filter clean?  Is the air filter clean? Is the spark plug clean?

Comment: Starter cranks, air filter is clean (removing it makes no difference), have fuel flow just fine.  I will replace the plug tomorrow

Comment: On my little lawn tractor the switch failed, when mowing it would die and backfire. That switch was not shorted but open , as a safety device it would not let the tractor run. I put a jumper in place of the switch and it started and ran fine. I was going to buy a new switch and my wife said (well can't say that here she hated having to restart every time she got off) I am not advocating defeating a safety device but it may point you to the problem.

Comment: Did you short it at the switch, or at the engine?  My problem is that if the switch wire is shorted I need to do this after the short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found what it was.  The plug was OK, and I laid it on the engine block and cranked the mower to verify a spark.  It had a spark so I figured it was fuel.

I took off the air filter cover and the 2 bolts that hold the air filter housing on the carb and removed the housing.  On the float bowl of the carb there was a wire coming off and going to a jumper that was not connected.  The other end of the jumper went to ground.  When I hooked this back up (i.e. re-connected the wire via the jumpers), it worked like new.

I have no idea what that is, maybe something that helps atomize the fuel, or a fuel pump relay?

Dunno, but it was electrical, just not a safety switch like I thought.